# hiding the Select button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, gridview

I currently have a gridview that allows you to select the row by clicking anywhere on that row.  however, there is a problem.  The AutoGenerateSelectButton must be set to true.  This means that the select button is now visible and part of the grid view.  I wanted to know if there was a way to hide it without disrupting the grid size?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to hide the select buttons from the rendered markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered hiding the column with CSS? This can be done in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
protected void yourGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";
    // or e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "hidden-cell";
}
```

Comment: That was the method I had originally tried.  It messes up the grid though.  The rows get huge in size and becomes off with the header. I think it might be because of the jQuery autoscrollable and it doesnot effect the header.

Comment: Do you have it behind a `if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) { }` check? If so, it'll only hide the rows and won't affect the header/footer. This could screw up your table display.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the entire row like this

```
protected void grdView_OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    grdView.Rows[rowNumber].Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: That method did not seem to work.  It would not allow my data to bind for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
                <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataKeyNames="BillingAccountNo" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgBillingInformation_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>

                        <asp:BoundField DataField="field" HeaderText="field" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="field" HeaderText="field" />
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Button" ControlStyle-CssClass="hidden" ItemStyle-CssClass="hidden" HeaderStyle-CssClass="hidden" FooterStyle-CssClass="hidden" />
                    </Columns>                     
                </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspect each row and hide/adjust label as needed:

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in gv.Rows)
            {
                if (r.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    TableCell editCell = r.Cells[0];
                    if (editCell.Controls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        LinkButton editControl = editCell.Controls[0] as LinkButton;
                        // control[1] is a literal space
                        LinkButton selectControl = editCell.Controls[2] as LinkButton;
                        editControl.Text = "New Edit Label Text";
                        //Ensure "Select" control, not "Cancel" control 
                        selectControl.Text = selectControl.Text == "Select" ? "New Select Label Text" : selectControl.Text;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on derek's answer, this is what I've done

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" Visible="false">
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="BillingAccountNo" OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="dgBillingInformation_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field" HeaderText="field" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="field" HeaderText="field" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" ButtonType="Button" Visible="true" />
    </Columns>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="LightCyan" ForeColor="DarkBlue" Font-Bold="true" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I put the select button right at the end of the gridview and use derek's code behind to mask the last row, eliminating the problem of the hidden select button screwing up with the table headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide an entire column and then display it again after you're done with it by using the following..

```
YourGridView.columns(0).Visible = False //Will hide the entire first column with all the select links in there.
```

Will also shift the header columns to the left so they match up correctly for printing, etc...

Then when you need to display it again, just change the attribute to true again.
That's VB syntax, you'll probably want to use the [] for the column index in C#.